# A program that works out all the different ways £2.50 can be made using any number of coins

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

2 fiddy

It is possible to make £2.50 in the following way:

```
1×£1 + 2×50p + 2×20p + 1×5p + 1×2p + 3×1p
```

Write a program that works out all the different ways £2.50 can be made using any number of coins.

Is there a simpler way to do all this below?

```
coins = [100,50,20,10,5,2,1]
number_of_coins = int(input("How many coins do you have: "))
num_of_ways = []

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(6):
        for k in range(13):
            for l in range(26):
                for m in range(51):
                    for n in range(126):
                        for o in range(251):
                            possible = [i*coins[0],j*coins[1],k*coins[2],l*coins[3],m*coins[4],n*coins[5],o*coins[6]]
                            if sum(possible) == 250 and i+j+k+l+m+n+o == number_of_coins:
                                num_of_ways.append([i,j,k,l,m,n,o])

rd = tuple(num_of_ways) #Remove Duplicates
for a in rd:
        print(f'{rd[a][0]}×£1 + {rd[a][1]}×50p + {rd[a][2]}×20p + {rd[a][3]}×10p + {rd[a][4]}×5p + {rd[a][5]}×2p + {rd[a][6]}×1p')
```

Comment: How did you decide the bounds for the `range`s? Why does the calculation of `possible` use only `i` and `j`, and not the other loop variables?

Comment: Do you know how to find the number of non-negative integer solutions of a linear equation in n variables? If so you can solve it mathematically and just write a program to plug in the values in the solution. In this case, you want the number of non-negative integer solutions to 100a + 50b + 20c + 5d + 2e + f = 250.

Comment: You can make 250 at maximum using the coins bounds.(i for 100, because you cannot make 250 with more then 2 100's)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , I need all the possible ways.That will give only smallest number of coins.

Answer (score 2):

Use recursion.

Hint: you can use either 0, 1 or 2 100p coins (how do you determine how many can be used?); regardless of how many of these coins you use, you need to make up the remaining sum (how do you compute this?) using coins of denomination `[50,20,10,5,2,1]` (how do you determine this, from the initial `coins` list?). Your base case is when there are no `coins` available to use and no sum to produce; you can do this in exactly one way (an empty list of coins). The only really tricky part is combining the results from all the recursive calls: for each result from the recursion, you need to factor in the appropriate number of coins from the current call, and then collate the results across each recursive call you made.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this a bit more?